# Is there a way to write this function recursively?

Tags: python, function, for-loop, recursion, string-length

I'm still new to coding, how would I perform this function recursively? The code does not need to be fixed, it runs as is. Rather, I'm trying to perform the same function but recursively instead. Currently, I'm just using a for-loop to run the code.

```
def longestSeqFinder(tryList):

    longestSeqList = []
    for i in tryList:
        longestSeq = (max(i, key = len))
        longestSeqList.append(longestSeq)

    return longestSeqList
```

---

To give an example of how this, non-recursive, function works:

```
>>> longestSeqFinder([['0', '234', '6', ''],
                      ['', '', '', '', '', '', ''],
                      ['012', '', '5678']])
['234', '', '5678']
```

Comment: tryList output == 
(first line) [['0', '234', '6', ''], ['', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['012', '', '5678']]
(second line) [['0', '234', '6', ''], ['', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['012', '', '5678']]

Comment: Please edit the question as to what exactly needs to be fixed, it is very unclear.

Comment: I edited the question. Hopefully it makes more sense now. I'm trying to perform the same function as a recursive function instead of a for-loop function.

Comment: Yes, I got it but nobody knows what input you are giving to the function and what output it is giving if you could put that in it would help people understand your implementation of the function and not leave them guessing around as to what this does.

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to just work out the max of the first element passed into the function, and prepend this to the result of calling yourself with the rest of the list.

That is to say,

```
def get_longest(lst):
    return [max(lst[0], key=len)] + get_longest(lst[1:]) if lst else []
```

One-liner too! :)

---

And a little test shows it does the job:

```
>>> get_longest([['0', '234', '6', ''],
                 ['', '', '', '', '', '', ''],
                 ['012', '', '5678']])
['234', '', '5678']
```